# Giving an arbitrary container, deduce a container type of a related type

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, type-alias

Say I have a templated class `Wrapper`, is there a way to create a type alias template that automatically deduce a container of `Wrapper <T>` from a container of `T`, so that:

- `alias(Wrapper, vector<int>)` would become `vector<Wrapper<int>>`
- `alias(Wrapper, map<int, string>)` would become `map<Wrapper<int>, Wrapper<string>>`
- `alias(Wrapper, array<int, 10>)` would become `array<Wrapper<int>, 10>`

---

So far the best attempt I've got is:

```
template<template<typename> typename U, template<typename...> typename Container, typename ...T>
using alias = std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(std::declval<Container<U<T>...>>())>;
```

However there are two problems:

1. <del>It must be called with syntax like:</del>This version need to be called like(which is not ideal): `alias(vector, Type)` and `alias(map, Key, Value)`. I would love to use `alias(vector<Type>)` and `alias(map<Key, Value>)` if possible.
2. It is not compatible with `std::array` since the second template parameter of `array` is `size_t` not a type. I guess I could create a second type alias and call the corresponding one based on the container type, but I would prefer not have to do that.

Comment: arguments of `alias` are types or values?

Comment: *"It must be called with syntax like"* - Why is that such a hard requirement? And it's incompatible with more than just `std::array`. `std::vector` and `std::map` have more that just the "common" parameters. There's an allocator parameter, and even a compare functor parameter. You wrap those too? I doubt `Wrapper<Alloc>` is gonna be itself a valid alllocator every type.

Comment: Passing types in parentheses like this will require macros.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica *"It must be called with syntax like"* -  Sorry if the wording makes it unclear. I was meant to callout the problem here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you need, but specialization of class template can handle this nicely:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <map>
#include <string>

template<template<typename> typename Wrapper, typename Container>
struct repack;

template<template<typename> typename Wrapper, typename ValueT>
struct repack<Wrapper, std::vector<ValueT>>
{
    using type = std::vector<Wrapper<ValueT>>;
};

template<template<typename> typename Wrapper, typename ValueT, std::size_t N>
struct repack<Wrapper, std::array<ValueT, N>>
{
    using type = std::array<Wrapper<ValueT>, N>;
};

template<template<typename> typename Wrapper, typename Key, typename Value>
struct repack<Wrapper, std::map<Key, Value>>
{
    using type = std::map<Wrapper<Key>, Wrapper<Value>>;
};

template<template<typename> typename Wrapper, typename Container>
using repack_t = typename repack<Wrapper, Container>::type;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/naz9v48vb

It passes tests specified by you.

Comment: This was the way I was going to suggest as it avoids wrapping all of the default template parameters like the allocator or comarator/hasher.  +1

Answer (score 3):

There are no ways currently to be generic and mix non-type-template-parameters with type-template-parameter or template-template-parameter.

Then for your `alias` restricted to type-template-parameter, you might do something like:

```
template <template <typename> class Inner, typename Container>
struct alias;

template <template <typename> class Inner,
          template <typename...> class C,
          typename... Ts>
struct alias<Inner, C<Ts...>>
{
    using type = C<Inner<Ts>...>;
};

template <template <typename> class Inner, typename Container>
using alias_t = typename alias<Inner, Container>::type;
```

usage would be

`alias_t<Wrapper, vector<int>>` and not `alias(Wrapper, vector<int>)`.

But as mentioned in comment, the generic way will wrap all parameters, including the default ones (such as `Allocator`).

Selecting the specializations as Marek R showed might be more appropriate.

Comment: Your approach is more universal, but can't make it compile (already fixed couple things) https://godbolt.org/z/MbvWfe9q8

Comment: I suspect that allocator template argument of container is wrapped that it why it fails tests.

Comment: @MarekR It is: *But as mentioned in comment, the generic way will wrap all parameters, including the default ones (such as Allocator).*

Comment: @MarekR: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rzTfo8K9Y) with changed expectation.